# Utility network spatial data of any kind, anywhere

Tags: geospatial, network-structure

I am looking to find as many sources for utility network datasets as possible. Most preferable would be some that are at the city/town scale. This could be anything from water to electricty to gas to fibre optic to sewer to anything. It can be from any city or town anywhere in the world, as long as it has information in individual features and preferably forms an actual connected linear network.

The reason I am looking for this is to find potential samples for use in the [Utility Network ADE](https://github.com/TatjanaKutzner/CityGML-UtilityNetwork-ADE), a data format which is supposed to be able to handle any and all utility networks.

A good example of the kind of data I am looking for is the various networks provided by Nanaimo, Canada:

- [Water network](https://www.nanaimo.ca/open-data-catalogue/DataBrowser/nanaimo/Water#param=NOFILTER--DataView--Results)
- [Stormwater network](https://www.nanaimo.ca/open-data-catalogue/DataBrowser/nanaimo/Storm#)
- [Sanitary sewer network](https://www.nanaimo.ca/open-data-catalogue/DataBrowser/nanaimo/Sewers#param=NOFILTER--DataView--Results)

Any data format is acceptable as long as it has a spatial component (.shp, .kmz, geojson, sqlite, geopackage, whatever)

Comment: https://wiki.openmod-initiative.org/wiki/Transmission_network_datasets ??

Comment: That's certainly a good source, I am most interested in finding regional network datasets (i.e for towns and cities), but thank you of course for this contribution, it's all useful and I think we can put it to good use.

Comment: something else i found is the australia investor map, which has data for electric lines as well as oil & gas pipelines: https://www.nationalmap.gov.au/investormap/

Answer (score 1):

Is ArcGIS online Feature Layer an acceptable format? I found hundreds of utility line layers by searching for "utility line" [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=utility%20line&start=1&num=20&focus=layers-weblayers-features). For example:

[Utility Line](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c898c3222e1b4f3ea53ccf67c78aa2a6) by Land Information Ontario

> Identifies utility lines in Ontario.

[Electric Transmission Lines - California Energy Commission [ds1198]](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a5b51de6cb3b47c794021c4358fad97e) by
BIOS_Admin

> The California Energy Commission (CEC) Electric Transmission Line geospatial data layer has been created to display the electric transmission grid in California. When used in association with the CEC Power Plant and CEC Electric Substation geospatial data layers, viewers can analyze the geographic relationships with the electric transmision grids across utilities, counties and state.The transmission line data, as one of the CEC''s critical infrastructure spatial data will be used to: 1. Support the CEC/STEP/Strategic Transmission Planning and Corridor Designation Office in corrdior study and transmission line siting; 2. Support the CEC staffs various analysis by providing general geographic reference information; 3. Enhance communication between and among government agencies on emergecy management, resource management, economic development, and environmental study;4. Provide illustration of critical infrastructure spatial data to the public or other agencies in hardcopy format.

[Sewer Utility Lines - City of Chilliwack](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=51f927cc855e4aed9e6b9745edfedf99) by andrewboan

> Linear pipes representing lateral connections from property boundary to sewer pipes in the sewer network. Properties boundary to structure can be residential, commercial or industrial. Linear features represent gravity mains, force mains, siphons, stubs and service connections in the sanitary network.

This is just a few examples; there are hundreds more.

Some layers have detailed attribute data, and others don't.

You don't need an ArcGIS license to view these layers online. I haven't tested any further, but it looks like you can load them into a GIS program via the REST service URL. I'm not sure if you can download the data or if you can only use it through the REST service. There is a Geoprocessing Tool called [Download ArcGIS Online Feature or AGS Feature/Map Service](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1713ea2a9e974101b19739b23ba9ac04), which I would guess you need ArcGIS to use.